# ggplot how to get separate plots for each month in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like get a separate plot for each month (12 plots in total for each month). I'm using nycflights13 dataset.

```
by_tailnum <- group_by(flights, tailnum)
delay <- summarise(by_tailnum,
                   count = n(),
                   dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
                   delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
delay <- filter(delay, count > 20, dist < 2000)




ggplot(delay, aes(dist, delay)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = count), alpha = 1/2) +
  labs(x="Distancia (millas)", y="Retraso (mins.)") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'gam') +
  scale_size_area() +
  ggtitle("Relación entre distancia y retrasos en los vuelos") +
  scale_radius(name="Núm. vuelos")
```

I have tried adding the following with

```
nycflights13::flights$month <- month(as.Date(Date))
```

But I'm getting the error;
    Error: could not find function "month"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the function is `months()`

Comment: The `flights` dataset already has a column of `month`.

Comment: Your attempt fails because there's no R function `month` in the base packages, or in `ggplot` or `dplyr`, which, we can only guess, you have already attached. There is one in the `lubridate` package. eg `lubridate::month(as.Date("1970-01-01"))` and there's a `months` package in the base packages which returns the month name.

Comment: Even with `lubridate` or `months`, this still fails: `month(as.Date(Date))` because where is `Date` here? There's no such thing, and there's no reason to expect R to look for it anywhere else. So that would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month is already in the flights dataset so you could do somethin like this:

```
   library(dplyr)
    library(nycflights13)
    library(ggplot2)

    data("flights")
    by_tailnum <- group_by(.data = flights, month, tailnum)
    delay <- summarise(by_tailnum,
                       count = n(),
                       dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
                       delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
    delay <- filter(delay, count > 20, dist < 2000)




    ggplot(delay, aes(dist, delay)) +
            geom_point(aes(size = count), alpha = 1/2) +
            labs(x="Distancia (millas)", y="Retraso (mins.)") +
            geom_smooth(method = 'gam') +
            scale_size_area() +
            ggtitle("Relación entre distancia y retrasos en los vuelos") +
            scale_radius(name="Núm. vuelos") + 
            facet_grid(month ~ .)
```

Comment: You can also add the month name with `flights$Month = months(flights$time_hour)` and then group/facet by that.

Comment: flights$Month = months(flights$time_hour)
by_tailnum <- group_by(flights,month, tailnum)
delay <- summarise(by_tailnum,
                   count = n(),
                   dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
                   delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
delay <- filter(delay, count > 20, dist < 2000)
  

  scale_radius(name="Núm. vuelos")+
  facet_grid(flights$Month ~ .) But Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) :   At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Comment: How can I get the months January,February, in the correct order?,I mean first Januar,then February etc..instead of the alphabetical order displayed?

Comment: You can switch to month name within the call to ggplot. Instead of just using `delay` for the data frame in the call to ggplot, do this: `delay %>% ungroup %>% mutate(month=month.name[month], 
                                    month=factor(month, levels=month.name))`.